# Laravel running slow with components and include

Tags: php, laravel, components, include

I consider that my laravel application running slower and slower, the more @components or @include I use in a page.
For example, it takes over 30 seconds to load a page.

But when I replaces `@include('backend.parts.dropdownItems')` and `@include('backend.parts.buttons')` with the exact same code, as in the dropdownItems and buttons file, than it takes  "only" 10.5 seconds. Still way too long time, but at least the page doesn't running out of time.

Anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?
Or how I can solve it?
I think just to duplicate code is very ugly solution, and not good for administration in the future...

I think I use laravel 5.x and php 7.x.

Page code:

```
...some code...
 @foreach($items as $item)
            <tr>
                <td class="d-lg-none d-xl-none">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dpm">
                        <div>Item:</div>
                        <div>@include('backend.parts.dropdownItems')</div>
                        <div>@include('backend.parts.buttons')</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a
                    href="{{ route('xxx', $item->id) }}">{{ $item->title }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>@include('partials.another_button')
                    {{ $item->name }}
                </td>
                <td class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-table-cell">Some info</td>
                <td>{{ $item->created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->address }}</td>
                <td class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-table-cell">
                    @include('backend.parts.dropdownItems')
                </td>
                <td class="text-center d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-table-cell">
                    @include('backend.parts.buttons')
                </td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
...some code...
```

`@include('backend.parts.dropdownItems')` contains this part of code:

```
<?php 
$userBrowser = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

if (preg_match('/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/', $userBrowser) ) { /* Chrome*/
    ?>
      <form id="applicationStatusForm" autocomplete = "off"> 
      {!! Form::select('status', $list, $list->id, ['class' =>
                    'change_status', 'data-application_id' => $list->id]) !!}
      </form>
    <?php
      }
 else {
    ?>
        {!! Form::select('status', $list, $list->id, ['class' =>
                    'change_status', 'data-application_id' => $list->id]) !!}
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

And `@include('backend.parts.buttons')` contains:

```
@can('user.show')
@if($item->Comments()->whereNotNull('id')->count() > 0 &&
    $item->Comments()->join('users', 'users.id', 'comments.user_id')->where('active', '=',
    1)->count() > 0)
    <span><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></span>
@endif
@component('components.button.square.link', ['remote' => route('item.show',
        $item->id))
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
@endcomponent
@endcan
@can('item.destroy')
    @component('components.button.square.destroy', ['remote' => route('item.destroy',
        $item->id)])
    @endcomponent
@endcan
@if($item->title == 'Text')
    @component('components.button.square.modal', ['remote' => route('item.modal.editPlace', $item)])
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    @endcomponent
@endif
```

**Update, here is from controller:**
This code is called when I press on submit-button, and then a table been rendered out of this data (@foreach($items as $item) is rows in the table).

```
public function submit(Request $input)
    {
        if(Input::get('search')) {
            $a =  $this->search($input);
            Session::put('search_terms', $a);
            Session::save();

            return view( 'backend.item.index' )->with( [
                'items' => $a['items'],
                'title'        => $a['title'],
                'skills'       => $a['skills'],
                'text'         => $a['text'],
                'status'       => $a['status'],
                'total'        => $a['total'],
                'filtered'     => $a['items']->count(),
                'period' => $a['period'],
            ] );
        }
    }
```

**Update from search function:**

```
function search(Request $request, $time = false) { 
    if(!is_null($request->text)|| $request->active != 0 ||  !is_null($request->county) || $request->status != 0){
        $dateStart = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-01-01');
    } else {
        $dateStart = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    $dateEnd = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $period = new Period($dateStart, $dateEnd);
    $total = Items::all()->count();

    if($request->li_id != 1){
            $items= Item::wherehas( 'li', function ($q) {
            $q->where( 'valid_to', '>=', carbon::now());

            if(auth()->user()->nr!= \Config::get('NR')){
                $q->where('nr', '=', auth()->user()->nr);
            }});
                
        }
    else
    {
            if(auth()->user()->d_nr!= \Config::get('D_NR')){ 
                $items= Item::where('d_nr','=', auth()->user()->d_nr);
                $items= $items->wherehas( 'li', function ($q) {
                    $q->where( 'valid_to', '>=', carbon::now());
                } );
            }else
            {
                $items = Item::wherehas( 'li', function ($q) {
                    $q->where( 'valid_to', '>=', carbon::now());
                    
                    if(auth()->user()->d_nr != \Config::get('D_NR')){
                        $q->where('d_nr', '=', auth()->user()->d_nr);
                    }});
            }
        }
$title = __( 'Search results' ) . ( isset( $li ) ? ', ' . $li->title
            : '' );

$items= $items->get();



 if($request->li_id )
        {
                $items= $items->filter( function ( $a ) use ( $request ) {
                    return ( $a->li_id && $a->li->id == $request->li_id );
                } );
        }
    
    if ( $request->status ) 
    {
            $items= $items->filter( function ( $a ) use ( $request ) {
                return ( $a->status && $a->status->id == $request->status );
            } );
    }
    
    $li_id   = $request->li_id;
    $county       = $request->county;
    $d  = $request->d;
    $li_active = $request->li_active;
    $status = $request->status;

    return compact( 'items',
     'title',
    'status',
    'total',
    'items',
    'li_id',
    'county',
    'd',
    'li_active',
    'period'
        );
   }
```

Comment: Okay, i think i can see the issue here
Can you update your question and post the code of the controller which is rendering these blade files?

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama now I have updated my question with code from controller

Comment: can you post the code for the `search()` function ?
I know this might be too much, but we must run after the code to see where the issue exactly

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama It is actually a lot of code in that function. 
When you clicked on search button, you could have choosen multiple search criteria. So it is a lot of if/else, depending on checkboxes, dropdown and textarea. But I could paste in some of it. They all look pretty much the same.
When I have tested, I have just filtered by one dropdown and nothing more of the search criteria.

Comment: no problem, I think this code should be enough to give us an idea. The `search()` function looks good. however, maybe you're returning a big number of items inside this function, you could use pagination here to retrieve chunks of the DB results. Another related issue is how you count items of variable `$total` using this line `Items::all()->count()`. You're fetching all records from the database and loading them into the memory then counting them, you can simply count them from the database using `Items::count()`, it's much faster and more efficient in terms of memory.

Comment: If these steps didn't help you, then we should look at `backend.parts.buttons`. There are some odd things there. But first let's try the above solution and let me know how things goes.

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama Unfortunately it does not helped to change to `Items::count( )`. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252963/discussion-between-eyad-mohammed-osama-and-maria).